# Why we can overwrite standard class?

Tags: apex

A user reported an error in Salesforce due to this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: isRunningTest

I know that this was because someone has created a class by the name `Test`.

I know we can specify the full namespace `System.Test.isRunningTest()` in the test class to fix the error.

But shouldn’t `Test` be protected as reserved identifiers in the first place?
Is there any specific reason why we are allowed to create such classes?

I also tried to create classes with other built-in class names and they can be overwritten: Messaging, Limits, Database, and the list can be long.

Some other classes cannot be overwritten: Datetime, SObject, Time.

Comment: This is a question for the Apex team at SFDC, not for this forum, really.

Answer (score 2):

The only limits are the [reserved keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm). For better or worse, we're allowed to create this situation on a number of words that should have been reserved, such as Schema, Test, Id, and Database.

This means you can create problems for an entire org with a public class by those names, or even locally within a class by declaring a variable with those names. As a practical matter, organizations should set up PMD rules or code review rules to automatically fail any symbols that could cause this sort of conflict.

I don't have an explanation for why this was allowed (especially Test, which is the most likely word to be used inappropriately, and Schema, which you *can't* access via `System.Schema`), but the main problem *now* is that they can't really change that behavior without breaking orgs that have violated this limitation.